vgrename but without writing to storage (read-only PV)
when dealing with image backups of systems I often run into issues with the VG within the mounted backup image having the same name as the live one.
Also because the backup is read-only I cannot simply vgrename the backup one eihter. How can I mount a partition from within such a LVM to extract files more easily?
Currently I'm using KVM to mount it to a live-CD linux and then copy files via SSH. There must be a better way.
I also considered renaming the hosts vg, but that is not ideal, as after the next backup I'd have to do it again.
Is there some way to tell vgrename to only rename in "running config" but not sync the rename to disk? Or bring a non unique VG online by some kind of filtering on the backing PVs? I've seen some commands have a --devices PV argument, however either I'm using it incorrectly or it alone is not enough to bring a logical volume online from within a non unique volume group.
I also tried using containers, but with --privileged I get all of the /dev into the container and therefore it also sees both.
Without and with only e.g. --device /dev/dm-3 it doesn't see anything from LVM, however it also doesn't appear to be able to mount a new one as pvs is empty and pvs /dev/dm-3 returns with "  Cannot use /dev/dm-3: device is missing sysfs info" only an error.
Can someone help?

I guess your backups are at the physical volume level, so the volume groups have the same UUIDs as well? That's not something LVM copes with well. See a related question on Server Fault.

yes and no, currently at least the only issue is that all systems have been installed using "vg0" as the root volume group. But yea, dealing with duplicate UUIDs is the next issue. Ideally I'm looking for a solution for both, but the non unique UUID case is probably way more tricky...

LVM identifies things via UUIDs internally. You can often get around non-unique names by specifying UUIDs, but non-unique UUIDs are probably hopeless without virtualization.

Ok, as I thought, so ignoring the non unique UUID ones for now. How would I get a vgs online with a duplicate name (and unique UUIDs)? Doing vgchange -ay UUID doesn't work. It doesn't find the volume group.

vgchange also has a --uuid argument, however that also doesn't work as when combined with -ay it errors out with "Command does not accept option: --activate y.". @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' could you please explain how to use the UUID here?
